# Access data not opening in excel

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am trying to import data from an access database to excel but when I click on Data -> From Access and select my file in excel nothing happens. I have had this working in the past. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Do you get the popup box that lists the tables/queries in your access database?

Comment: no, it just goes back to the spreadsheet and does nothing. That box used to come up but not any more.

Comment: Does your access table have the raw tables or are they linked tables?  I believe Excel only shows raw tables or queries, using the import(link) feature.

Comment: ...or if anyone else is importing tables from Access, then it might be putting Access in a read-only state.  Not sure if this will impact your import though.  (I just tested this and froze out all my other users from my database)